# EditText disappears when user press on and keyboard appear

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, autolayout, android-designer

I have 3 forms in EditText and I need to readjust the position automatically when the user click in form and keyboard appear, in my manifest.xml I added this line:
" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" "

This is my XML Code of The screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_farm"

    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLogar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="136dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bgbuttonform"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_check_black_24dp"
        android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@android:color/black"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:text="@string/confirmar_dados"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_selecionar_foto"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_btn_rounded_img"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:text="Selecione uma foto"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextEmailUser"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_editextrounded"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint=" Digite aqui seu email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editTextPassword"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextUser" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextUser"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_editextrounded"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Digite aqui seu nome"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editTextEmailUser"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_selecionar_foto" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_editextrounded"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Digite aqui sua senha"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonLogar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextEmailUser" />

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageFotoUser"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:civ_border_width="1dp"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_selecionar_foto"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btn_selecionar_foto"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btn_selecionar_foto"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btn_selecionar_foto"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewInicial"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="175dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="178dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="33dp"
        android:text="Seja bem vindo(a) ao Agro Lucros!\nPreencha o formulário abaixo para seguir"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:textSize="18.5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_selecionar_foto"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textJaTemConta"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="94dp"
        android:text="Já possui uma conta? Clique aqui!"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonLogar" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I need basically when keyboard appear the edit text scrolling to up screen, sorry for my explanation.

Comment: try adding your buttons and edit texts to a Scrollview since when the input keyboard is appearing you have room for the layout to be scrolled up screen

Comment: Some buttons have a fixed (Weight and Height), is possible use ScrollView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding to what @dmak2709 has advised above.

I'd suggest you to use `NestedScrollView` for all your layout like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

 <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLogar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="136dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bgbuttonform"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_check_black_24dp"
        android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@android:color/black"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:text="@string/confirmar_dados"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_selecionar_foto"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_btn_rounded_img"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:text="Selecione uma foto"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextEmailUser"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_editextrounded"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint=" Digite aqui seu email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editTextPassword"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextUser" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextUser"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_editextrounded"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Digite aqui seu nome"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editTextEmailUser"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_selecionar_foto" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_editextrounded"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Digite aqui sua senha"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonLogar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextEmailUser" />

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageFotoUser"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:civ_border_width="1dp"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_selecionar_foto"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btn_selecionar_foto"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btn_selecionar_foto"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btn_selecionar_foto"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewInicial"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="175dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="178dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="33dp"
        android:text="Seja bem vindo(a) ao Agro Lucros!\nPreencha o formulário abaixo para seguir"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:textSize="18.5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_selecionar_foto"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textJaTemConta"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="94dp"
        android:text="Já possui uma conta? Clique aqui!"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonLogar" />

 </LinearLayout>



</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Check out this [page](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/move-layout-when-keyboard-shown/) if you want more information on this.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I understand now, this is a class from the activity  that is used, i got it! THANKS!

Comment: NestedScrollView need imports on .java?

The error " NestedScrollView - class not found" appear now.

Comment: It Happened because i'm use Androidx, and needed "androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView" in .XML, thanks.

Comment: Great @lukecross let me know if you require any other help related to this.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` in your Manifest as follows. Because I think you are missing the `adjustPan` attribute.

```
<activity
            android:name=".activityname"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Also you can enclose the editext in a `ScrollView`.

Comment: Seems correct to me, thanks! i'll try, your answer and the answer of _the_underrated are both fine to me!